# linux shell: find -exec in find -exec

Tags: find

I want to execute `chmod 555` on all files and directories I get with the following command (it returns the directory test and all files and directories in it):

```
find ~/.config/google-chrome -type d -name test -exec find {} \;
```

Comment: Find traverses the file system hierarchy recursively. Executing find from find makes no sense. Not even ever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this very case, you can use `chmod -R` as per [user26112's answer](/a/84266), but in the general case, you can do:

```
find ~/.config/google-chrome -type d -name test -exec sh -c '
  for i do
    find "$i" -exec chmod 555 {\} +
  done' sh {} +
```

The trick being to use a shell and use quoting (like `{\}` or `{"}"`) so that the inner `{}` is not expanded by the outer `find` (accounting for those implementations of `find` that still expand `{}` even when it's only part of an argument).

GNU `find` 4.9.0 or newer also supports getting the list of files to work on from stdin as NUL delimited records, so you can do:

```
find -files0-from <(
    find ~/.config/google-chrome -type d -name test -print0
  ) -exec chmod 555 {} +
```

With older versions, you can do something similar using GNU `xargs` and `sh` to reorder the arguments:

```
xargs -r0a <(
    find ~/.config/google-chrome -type d -name test -print0
  ) sh -c 'exec find "$@" -exec chmod 555 {} +' sh
```

(`<(...)` is *process substitution*, a ksh feature also supported by zsh and bash, not to be confused with `yash`'s *process redirection*).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `chmod`'s `-R` flag to change the permissions of the directory and all of the files and directories in the hierarchy beneath it.

```
find ~/.config/google-chrome -type d -name test -exec chmod -R 555 '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want two `find -exec`, try the following

`find /etc -type f -exec sh -c 'find "$0" -exec echo {\} \;' {} \;`

(that will just pass to `echo` command what `find` did find)

`find /etc -type d -exec sh -c 'find "$0" -type f -exec echo "$0" {\} \;' {} \;`

(some useful example: prints dir name and list of files in it)

With using `sh -c` you can also resolve issue with pipes in the `find -exec` clause, also notice that passed arguments to `sh -c` will start from `$0` not from `$1` as usually do with shell script.

Comment: That doesn't work with the GNU find (as usually found on Linux based systems as the OP mentions he's using) and some other find implementations, because those expand `{}` even when they're not on their own as a single argument. So in your case, the first find would expand both `{}`. You forgot the quotes around `$0`.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas great, you're right! That is why I sometimes had to doublequote `$0` parameters.. Escaping the internal closing `}` curly brace is very tricky and smart) didn't notice that.

Comment: Note that you can avoid running one shell per directory, by using `+` instead of `\;` and a loop in the shell. I prefer not using `$0` there because `$0` is used for instance by the shell to display error messages which can cause confusion. Hence the extra `sh` argument to set `$0` in the solution I gave.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run this command. It will run on each directory, but the `+` argument to `find` will run the `chmod` with multiple "test" directories passed as arguments:

```
$ find ~/.config/google-chrome -type d -name test -exec chmod -R 555 '{}' +
```