# Can find reliably call itself from -exec without breaking the semantics of the two instances?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, arguments, recursive

Following http://superuser.com/questions/1780479 and http://superuser.com/questions/1777606, we issue the following script to compare times of the same–full-path symlinks under directories $1 and $2:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
find . -type l -exec bash -c "if [[ -h \"{}\" && -h \"$2/{}\" ]]; then if (test $(readlink \"{}\") = $(readlink \"$2/{}\")) then if (find \"$2/{}\" -prune -newer \"{}\" -printf 'a\n' | grep -q a) then echo \"{} is older than $2/{}\"; else if (find \"{}\" -prune -newer \"$2/{}\" -printf 'a\n' | grep -q a) then echo \"$2/{} is older than {}\"; fi; fi; fi; fi" \;
```

The usage is *compare_times.sh directory_1 directory_2* (where `compare_times.sh` is the name of the script).  We use it as demonstrated in the following example:

```
user@machine:/tmp/D1$ ls -lt --full-time /tmp/linked_file /tmp/D*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  0 2023-04-25 00:12:09.289942358 +0200 /tmp/linked_file

/tmp/D2:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 14 2023-04-25 00:07:00.265830604 +0200 lnk -> ../linked_file

/tmp/D1:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 14 2023-04-25 00:06:40.922078186 +0200 lnk -> ../linked_file
user@machine:/tmp/D1$ compare_times.sh . ../D2
./lnk is older than ../D2/./lnk
user@machine:/tmp/D1$
```

As you see, `find` calls `bash`, which itself calls `find`.  (Probably, this might be written more elegantly, but this is not the point now.)  Are there any issues with calling `find` from under `find` this way?

The man page of the `find` command doesn't say whether `find` is reenterant or not.  If `find` is not reentrant, we could hypothetically silently miss some output, i.e., some symlinks that have the same name and the same position inside the two directories and that point to equal filenames but that have different timestamps.

Comment: [Never ever do this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/12574). Moreover, this is not valid shell

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? What other commands are not reenterable? `find` is just a utility, and if it calls itself, it just calls itself. I have much _much_ more to say about the obvious _other_ issues in your code though, so if you update your question with whatever it is that you are having a problem with, we may be able to help you sort it out.

Comment: Rephrasing my previous comment: Yes, `find` can be called from `find` with no issues. However, your code has code injection vulnerabilities and quoting issues that may cause it to fail or behave in unexpected ways.  Since you explicitly discourage us from helping you with your code, I will say nothing further about that.

Comment: It seems [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1777606/432690) is the OP's main task. [This one](https://superuser.com/q/1780479/432690) followed; and now the one we're commenting on.

Comment: Related: [linux shell: find -exec in find -exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84265)

Comment: @GillesQuénot Thx! You can assume that all filenames I run the code on have been created by me or trustworthy folks. So, if code injection occurs, then only unintentionally. Which part do you refer to by “not valid shell”?

Comment: @Kusalananda Thx! You can assume that all filenames I run the code on have been created by me or trustworthy folks. So, if code injection occurs, then only unintentionally. As for the higher-level goal I wish to achieve, cf. https://superuser.com/questions/1777606 . Any help is welcome, be it the code itself or the high-lever goal.

Comment: @Kusalananda Concerning “What is the issue you are facing”: I was afraid that due to find calling itself, some output is missed, i.e., some symlinks that have the same name and the same position inside the two directories and that point to equal filenames but that have different timestamps could be missed.

Comment: @AlMa0: can you share a copy paste by editing your post with a use case when you have 2 symlinks with 2 different timestamps? It will helps everyone to understand, and to help you further. Your goal if to find symlinks that have different timestamps, right?

Comment: @GillesQuénot Done. Also other typos corrected. Yes, your understanding of the goal  is correct. Presuming the same name and the same path after `$1/` and `$2/`.

Answer (score 1):

> Not all commands are known to be reenterable.

Which ones are you thinking?

Usually, re-entrability comes into question with library functions that implicitly use some global state, and where calling the function twice at the same time, e.g. from within itself would mess up that state. (See e.g. [Why are malloc() and printf() said as non-reentrant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941271/why-are-malloc-and-printf-said-as-non-reentrant) on SO.)

But there's no global state between individual processes, they all have their own memory space and OS and the hardware make sure processes can't mess the memory of other processes. Of course, e.g. the filesystem is global state, but I'm not sure `find` needs to use it for saving state, and anyway respectable programs that do need temporary files are usually pretty good at using unique temporary files.

If state in the filesystem was an issue, it's hard to see how it would be specific to `find` processes called as each others children, but it'd already come up running any simultaneous `find` processes.

---

How useful it is to run one `find` from another is a whole another question, but I guess you could do this to find all regular files under directories called `x`...

```
$ mkdir -p {a/x,b,x}; touch {a/x,b,x}/foo.txt
$ find . -type d -name x -exec find {} -type f \;;
./a/x/foo.txt
./x/foo.txt
```

Comment: Answering “Which ones are you thinking?”: To be precise, I know of no GNU commands which have been *explicitly* documented as being reentrable or non-reentrable. Functions are a different matter; cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732882. Knowing the how folks (including myself) actually write code, it is usual that if an author of a piece of code thinks about any feature (here, reentrability), he/she documents this feature in some way or at least talks about it.

Comment: The global state, as you said, could be the file system in our case, say, temporary files (whether find uses them itself or calls library functions or other tools is a different matter). Also some tools which search for `find` among the process ids of the ancestors/descendants could hypothetically stop at the first found instance of `find`, while they need another one. Hypothetically, of course.

Comment: I suppose that `find -type d -exec mv {} ...` could be construed as non-reentrant particularly without the `-depth` option

Comment: @AlMa0, well you wrote that you know some commands are known not to be... it doesn't have to be a GNU command, any implementations would work as an example. But perhaps the distinction between a function and a command is rather important here, and due to how things work, re-entrabiliry of commands just isn't a thing to consider or document...

Comment: @AlMa0, why would some command search for `find` in its ancestors? Is there any plausible reason to do that? I mean, if we accept implausible issues, we could hypothesize a very solitary `cat` that looks for other `cat`s in the list of all processes and refuses to run if it finds one. Neither of those would be an issue with `find` itself, though, unless it's the one doing the looking.

Comment: In my example, the outer `find` is used to crawl through the directory structure, and the inner `find` is used only to check whether the timestamps of two symlinks differ (and has nothing to do with finding files itself).